# Enemy Within with older DLCs

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

So I have the Slingshot DLC and Enemy Within expansion.  Prior to the Enemy Within expansion there was a council mission that would ask if you would like to play the regular game or the Slingshot version.  With my first Enemy Within game it looks like it automatically started some Sling Shot missions.  Did these mission come with Enemy Within and can not be turned off?  Or if I uninstall Slingshot will the game go back to regular missions?

The slingshot missions are

> Friends In Low Places
>
>  Confounding Light 
>
>  Gangplank(the one I am having trouble with)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCOM: Enemy Within DOES NOT include Slingshot mission pack. You can toggle whether you want to play it in Advanced Options when starting the game ONLY if you have bought the DLC separately.

Screenshot taken in EW without Slingshot, note the presence of Meld.

[image: XCOM: EW, no Slingshot]

When available, Operation Slingshot checkbox appears right below Operation Progeny.

Comment: I can confirm that Enemy Within doesn't include the Slingshot DLC.

Comment: Thank you, so while it is not include Enemy Within moves the option from ingame right before the mission to a menu option.

Answer (score 5):

You can now select the various mission options including Slingshot in the "Advanced options" screen when you start a new game.

So Enemy Within includes the new missions and you have the option of playing them or not. They are available whether or not you purchased the Slingshot DLC.

When you start the game you also get asked if you want to play Enemy Within or Enemy Unknown.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you have Slingshot installed at time of the screenshot?

Comment: [My testing](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/148764/33619) contradicts this answer.

Comment: Yes I had Slingshot installed when I took the screenshot. My post has been edited by someone else to state that Slingshot is always available even if you didn't get the DLC - my original post did not state that.

Comment: But you still said that "Enemy Within includes the DLC" ;-)

Comment: The Xbox/PS versions do include the DLC.  The PC/Mac versions do not.